# Как единожды подписаться на событие динамически добавленного элемента?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Вот так я добавляю элемент

```
var div = document.createElement('div');
.... здесь много моей магии для сборки div объекта ...
document.body.appendChild(div);
```

На эти события хочу подписаться единожды:
webkitAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd oanimationend animationend

Answer (score 0):

```
el.one('webkitTransitionEnd otransitionend oTransitionEnd msTransitionEnd transitionend',   
    function(e) {

    // code to execute after transition ends

    }
);
```

Источник: http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/using-jquery-to-detect-when-css3-animations-and-transitions-end